# Google Sheets GUI displaying incorrect formula result, with correct result when analyzing the formula

Tags: debugging, google-sheets, boolean-operations

I have a weird issue that I don't understand the cause. A simple logical formula is displaying TRUE in the GUI, but FALSE (as it should) when analyzing the formula.

GUI display

[image: GUI display]

Formula analysis

[image: Formula analysis]

The spreadsheet is part of work with sensitive data and thus i cannot share. Also, cannot reproduce the error, and it seems to have instability - meaning that when the spreadsheet was filled, it was displaying the correct result (FALSE) but then at some point, on its own, it changed to TRUE.
I use lots of apps scripts in this sheet and so I am wondering if maybe using the equivalent of excel vba ActiveSheet.Calculate could help me here, but I don't understand why this is happening, if there's a way to prevent it from happening instead of remedying it, and i also don't see the button for a force calculate in the sheets and can't seem to find an apps script command line for that.

Comment: See secrets of debugging in [mcve]. You may even find your answer, when trying the first step of "restarting from scratch"

Comment: Disable **File > Settings > Calculation > Iterative calculation** if it is on.

Comment: @doubleunary , it is not on

Comment: @doubleunary , i do have lots of onEdit code in this spreadsheet. Could it be that my code execution failed, and that stopped the regular formulas from recalculating? If so, any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Apps Script runs on Google's servers, not in your computer. The preview result the formula shows, however, comes from code that runs in your web browser. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet where the issue can be reproduced. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: @doubleunary , made a copy, deleted all sensitive data, and grouped columns that aren't relevant

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dJe6-y_8i5t7vd9p5TGmEBQcKjZiNXymQfAUFoWOXu8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Possibly related: there is an [open ticket](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/181758745) regarding Google Sheets recalculation.

Comment: Probably unrelated: your script project has many globals. Of the order of nine API calls take place _every_ time you edit _any_ value in the spreadsheet. See these [onEdit(e) optimization tips](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).

Comment: @doubleunary , thanks!! will keep track of the open ticket.. commented there too.

Will look into the optimization tips as well!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create three new cells and split up the `AND` arguments to the 3 cells. See what is false and what should be true to pinpoint the error.

Comment: It's a GUI display error. The current P15 is a a number (not blank, thus TRUE under not isblank check, Q15 is filled, so FALSE, and P15 <> cobrar, so true.. AND(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) = FALSE. GSheets knows that. If recreate the formula, it shows that. But for some reason it is currently showing TRUE

Comment: @urieltm 1.So the problem is probably in Q15. How do you know it's filled? 2.If it's not there, check what format the cell is. It's possible to display FALSE as TRUE, but it shouldve been deliberately done. 3. What's the value of  ``=thiscell*1``?

Comment: i know for sure Q15 is filled, and it has a date in it as it should.
Additionally, =AT15*1 returns 1, which means it really thinks AT15 = TRUE (AT15 is the cell causing problems). 
AT15 is not formatted to display false as true. I am the only person that can edit it, and I have not done such formatting. It has conditional formatting on it to fill red if true but that's it.
What is really confusing me is that when mousing over the formula and calculating it step by step, it shows FALSE as the final result. But it thinks the result is TRUE otherwise.

Comment: Additionally, let me reemphasize.. If i copy the formula, delete it, paste it (so it forces a recalc), it then displays FALSE.

Comment: it seems to me, that the result didn't update after Q15 was filled in. I have lots of onEdit codes in this sheet and that may be the cause.

But what is the solution?

Comment: @urieltm Is there a formula in Q15?

Comment: No, just a date

Comment: made a copy, deleted all sensitive data, and grouped columns that aren't relevant

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dJe6-y_8i5t7vd9p5TGmEBQcKjZiNXymQfAUFoWOXu8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @urieltm FYI, [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: @urieltm As said in my answer, can you make 3 cells, one for each condition? And see which condition fails?

Comment: oh snap, good point!! how to I hide my email?

On the 3 cells.. I could, but it won't reproduce the error.. because recalculating the formula fixes it.. but i can't have to recalculate everything every time my code runs.. would be too much server time

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an [open ticket](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/181758745) regarding Google Sheets recalculation.

See if this array formula works better than your fill-down formula:

`=arrayformula( true = isblank(Q2:Q) * (P2:P <> "COBRAR") )`